# unknown attribute in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, import, roo-gem

Hey I am trying to import one excel file from my sheet to database but I don't know something is not working 
 getting unknown attribute :

My sheet is like this :

```
 name   title   jalebi  samosa  s1  s2  s3  
   1    4        7       7      7    7   7  
   2    5        6       6      6    6   6  
   3    6        5       5      5    5   5  
   4    7        4       4      4    4   4
```

And my Migration is :

```
      class CreateTest3s < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
      create_table :test3s do |t|
        t.string :name
        t.string :title
        t.string :jalebi
        t.string :samosa
        t.string :s1
        t.string :s2
        t.string :s3

        t.timestamps
      end
    end
  end
```

And my import code in model is :

```
    def self.import1(file)

   spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
          header = spreadsheet.row(1)
          (2..spreadsheet.last_row).each do |i|
            row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]
            puts row.to_hash
            product = find_by(id: row["id"]) || new
            product.attributes = row.to_hash
            product.save!
          end

 end
```

Whenever I am trying to run this I am getting this error:

```
 unknown attribute 'samosa ' for Test3.
```

and the value of hash is like this :

```
 {"name"=>1, "title"=>4, "jalebi"=>7, "samosa "=>9, "s1"=>7, "s2"=>7, "s3"=>7}
```

Comment: Can you show how you've defined the `Test3` model? What class is the `import1` method in? What line of code generates the `unknown attribute` error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the attribute you are trying to set is `"samosa "` with a trailing space. The attribute should be just `"samosa"` with no whitespace. I'm guessing your spreadsheet header is where the space is coming from.

Comment: that was the problem I figured it out I was unable to find what was the problem unless I see hash